# What is the difference between "$" and "#" in gatlings Expression Language when accessing session variables?

Tags: expression, gatling, scala-gatling

When writing gatling simulations in scala, it is possible to access session attributes with `#{}` and with `${}`. Both seem to do the same thing and I can't find anything in official doc or on SO defining their differences.

--> What is the difference between "$" and "#" in gatlings Expression Language when accessing session variables?

example

```scala
scenario("")
.exec(http("get foo")
  .get("http://localhost/")
  .check(jsonPath("$.foo").saveAs("foo")))
.exec(http("url from hashtag___").get("localhost/#{foo}")
.exec(http("url from dollarsign").get("localhost/${foo}")
```

The [official doc](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/) acknowledges that both types exists, but doesn't say what the differences are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${}` syntax is deprecated in favor of `#{}` but still works for now.
This deprecation is only mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/upgrading/3.6-to-3.7/#core), we'll add a warning in the page you mentioned.